# Deploy only the changes of a single Git commit

Tags: urbancode

I'm using IBM urban code deploy for code migration and Git is our source versioning system. I need to deploy only those components which are changed as part of a single commi, and not the whole repository.

As an example, for a single commit C1, lets assume there are only two files changed, so I need to extract and deploy only those two files and not the remaining of the branch.

Is there any specific setting at the component level to detect only the changed files and then proceed further?

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks, Kumarjit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kumarjit,

There is no easy way to do this using GIT plugin delivered with UrbanCode Deploy.

I suggest doing it this way:

1) Download all the files from the latest commit to machine
2) Create bash script that will:
 - List all the files changed in the latest commit
 - Delete all the downloaded files that are not on the list

There is no simple way how you can do it without scripting or creating your own plugin.

Comment: How can I get the last two versions of a component? The ${version.name} gives me the latest version of artifact import, but I want to get last-1 version also.

Comment: I would use Git, not UrbanCode for that. After downloading files to machine I would execute bash script that will get SHA of the previous commit using git rev-parse HEAD and later download commit -1